# Create Custom facebook Like button for each item

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My application shows several items whereby users can search. I want to place a like button for each item and this will be generated automatically using PHP. Before implementing it, I'm trying to test something which is not working.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/index.php?item=1" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

When I'm putting it on the page, the facebook like button is not appearing, any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to solve it,

ensure to place these codes blow after you declare `<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/index.php?item=1" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```